# jQuery acces var outside ready function

Tags: jquery

I am defining the following in my ready function

```
    js13(document).ready(function ($) {

            var socket = io.connect('http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080');


            socket.on('connect', function(){
                socket.emit('adduser', 'username');
            });


            socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {


                data = data.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/\"/g, "&quot;");
                js13("#chatboxcontent").append('<div class="ui-chatbox-msg"><b>' + username + ':</b> ' + data + '</div>');
                js13("#chatboxcontent").scrollTop(js13("#chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);                 

            });


            socket.on('updateusers', function(data) {
                $('#users').empty();
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('#users').append('<div>' + key + '</div>');
                });
            });            



});
```

How can i access the same socket var outside the ready function? I want to access it from within functions outside

Comment: ...just declare it *outside* of the function?

Comment: Because the .ready() function does not fire immediately. Socket will not be immediately defined, this is something to watch out for. If you reference socket immediately, the variable will be undefined. example: http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/c5rKz/

Answer (score 2):

Define the `socket` variable outside the ready function..

```
var socket;

js13(document).ready(function ($) {
   socket = io.connect('http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080');
```

**Note:** The var declaration is removed inside the ready function.

Comment: @Laine After declaring the `var socket` outside.. Did you remove the `var` inside the ready function.

Comment: Omg, i was typing var twice ://

Answer (score 1):

Just create the variable outside `ready ()`. Remember to REMOVE `var` declaration inside the `ready()` as then another local variable will be created.

```
var socket;
js13(document).ready(function ($) {

            socket = io.connect('http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080');
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var socket;

js13(document).ready(function ($) {

    socket = io.connect('http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080');
    //...
});
```